# Django last thirty days added with number

Tags: django, django-queryset

With a model like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How to grab stats data so it show recent added users for last 30 days with number of users added on that day.

Example:

```
2010-08-02: 220
2010-08-08: 1220
2010-08-14: 20
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

This answer is not useful. As `entered` is a `DateTimeField` the query will end up with a count of 1 for each value of `entered`. This is not what the OP wanted. (Thanks [dannyroa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112381/dannyroa))

Changing the type of `entered` to `DateField` should help.

**Original Answer**

You can use Django's [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) feature to do this. Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
q = User.objects.annotate(Count('entered')).order_by('-entered')
for user in q[0:30]:
    print "%s %s" % (user.entered, user.entered__count)
```

**Update**

You can slice the queryset and then pass it into the template.

```
# View 
def my_view(*args, **kwargs):
    queryset = User.objects.annotate(Count('entered')).order_by('-entered')
    context = dict(queryset = queryset[0:30])
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request, context))    

# Template
{% for user in queryset %}
    <td>{{ user.entered }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.entered_count }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, silly question, how to carry over q[0:30] data to templates

Comment: Pass your context as a dictionary argument not with RequestContext:
`return render_to_response('my_template.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))`

Comment: I haven't tested the code but wouldn't the result be like this?

2010-08-02 06:00:01 : 1

2010-08-02 06:10:10 : 1

2010-08-01 12:00:01 : 1

2010-08-01 12:10:10 : 1


It will be grouped by datetime not just by date so the count will always be one.